# Compact subspace

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Is the subspace $$C^k([0,T]) \subset C^{k-n}([0,T])$$ compact? I think the answer is no. But since $C^k$ is compactly embedded in $C^{k-n}$, it seems like it should be yes in some way. Can I do anything here?

($C^k$ is the space of $k$ times continuously differentiable functions)

Comment: What does the notation mean?

Comment: (Vector spaces are rarely compact!)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez $C^k$ is the space of $k$ times continuously differentiable functions. Yeah it doesn't look good...

Comment: You should have no problems finding a sequence which does not contain a convergent subsequence, then :-)

Comment: **Hint:** Every compact in normed space is bounded.

Comment: Probably it would be helpful for someone who reads this question also to know what do you mean with _compact_ . 

I think the definition is the following:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is true, I think, is that the unit ball of $C^k([0,T])$ is compact in $C^{k-n}([0,T])$.

EDIT: that should be "relatively compact", not "compact".

Comment: It should be relatively compact by Arzelà-Ascoli, but I don't think it is closed (you have no control on the derivatives of order $k-n+1, \ldots, k$, do you?).

Comment: Yes, true.  It is not compact.

Comment: This shows that the inclusion map $C^k \hookrightarrow C^{k-n}$ is compact, which is probably what the OP was thinking of.